# Nginx append to original url

Tags: nginx

I want to append /test.html at the end of a request without a dot, here is what I have

```
rewrite ^[^.]*$ https://$host$request_uri/test.html permanent;
```

It results a double slash in the end

```
https://www.testdomain/mypath//test.html permanent;
                            ----
```

Is there anyway to remove it, and what's the proper way to do it?

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^([^.]*?)/?$ https://$host$1/test.html permanent;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in the end

```
set $land_page "test.html"
rewrite ^[^.]*$ https://$host$request_uri$land_page permanent;
```